# Can I have multiple delimiters in jQuery Datatables YADCF plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have both " - " and "|" as delimiters in my database output, which I cannot change. I need to live with one or the other. I would rather use both. Is that possible? If not out of the box, can I modify it and how? Thanks in advance!

The reason for multiple delimiters is as follows:
1) If categories are nested, " - " is used to show hierarchy.
2) If multiple categories are assigned, "|" is used to display that fact.

Example output: "USA - Rocky Mountains Section" for one row, "USA - Gulf Coast Section" for another row, "Europe|Middle East" for yet another row.

I want to make a unified select object with all options separated, like this:

Select Region:
-USA
-Rocky Mountain Section
-Gulf Coast Section
-Europe
-Middle East

Example JS code:

```
oTable = $('#MasterEventsTable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ],[ 3, "asc" ]],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
                        { "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 1 ] }, 
                        { "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 4 ] }, 
                        { "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 5 ] }, 
                        { "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 6 ] } 
                    ]
    }).yadcf([
        {column_number : 2,  filter_type: "select", filter_container_id: "external_filter_container1", column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text", filter_default_label: "---ALL EVENTS---"} ,
        {column_number : 5,  filter_type: "select", filter_container_id: "external_filter_container2", column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text", filter_default_label: "---ALL CATEGORIES---"} ,
        {column_number : 6,  filter_type: "select", filter_container_id: "external_filter_container3", column_data_type: "text", text_data_delimiter: "/[-|]/", filter_default_label: "---ALL REGIONS---"} ,
        {column_number : 7,  filter_type: "select", filter_container_id: "external_filter_container4", column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text", filter_default_label: "---ALL---"}
        ]);
```

Comment: Can you try making a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem it might make it easier for us to help.

Comment: The code is too complicated to post as is, and too time-consuming to clean up :( -- I've edited the question to explain better, I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand exactly what you mean from the description, but I think you want to pass a regex as the `text_data_delimiter`

```
text_data_delimiter: /[-|]/
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dschu012/Zuk7L/2/)**

Comment: I tried it, and it did not work. I'm trying to make a select (drop down) with all the values to filter the table rows on, and the the column itself will be hidden from view. I also edited the original question to include JS code.

Comment: Note in your js you have `"/[-|]/"` which is different than `/[-|]/`.  One is a string, one is a regex.

Comment: Awesome, I totally overlooked that -- it works! Thanks a bunch, Danny!